# Where do local variables get stored at compile time?

Tags: c++, c, function, compilation

Maybe i'm missing something obvious, but isn't it during runtime that local variables get placed on the stack when the function containing the variables gets called.

Therefore when the compiler will step through our source code, it will place the operations of the function in the .text segment, but where do the variables get placed at compile time so they can be placed onto the stack at run-time? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the compiler option to save the assembly code, and see how it does it?

Comment: Q: What do you put in your closet before you've built your house?  A "variable" gets stored in "memory" - which doesn't exist before the program is loaded at runtime.  What's "compiled" is instructions for how to *access* the memory.  For example, local variable "x" might be stored at offset "2" from register "stack pointer".  The assembly instruction `mov eax, [esp + 2]` will read "x" into register "a" (presumably for further computation).

Comment: do they get stored in symbol tables?

Comment: There is no requirement by the standard for the compiler to use a stack or other management for storage at all.

Comment: @paulsm4: Initialisation values for static variables **have to** be stored somewhere by the compiler. The same for e.g. literals/initialisers and constants like `42`.

Comment: @Olaf: If I have `static char buf[10000];` (which is implicitly initialized to all zeros), there probably won't be 10000 bytes stored anywhere in the object file or executable. The space will be allocated at program load time. The executable just has to specify how much.

Comment: C does not specify anything about a _stack_ nor _.text segment_.  These are artifacts of a given compiler.  Post the compiler of interest.

Comment: @Olaf the initialised value may be in the code itself, such as `PUSH 42`. Or the compiler may decide to make it a register variable.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I should have been more precise: "The initialiser values have to be stored somewhere". Implicit initialisation is typically performed at startup. But actually the standard does not require that either; it is just a very common optimisation to reduce the size of the binary.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That's why I used an `int` constant. It "have to be stored somewhere" implies as an immediate value in the op-code itself, of course (ARM uses - among others - a literal pool typically close to the code for instance). I have to admit, I've never seen a CPU register which directly provides the value `42` without being loaded first ;-) Is that the CPU of [Deep Thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Thought_(The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)#Deep_Thought)? ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Local variables aren't placed anywhere at compile time.

The compiler generates code that, when executed at run time, will allocate space on the stack (typically; other schemes are possible). The compiler records information about each variable (name, type, size, offset relative to the stack pointer, etc.) and uses that information to generate code that creates, accesses, and finally deallocates the variable.

A technical digression: C doesn't have "local" and "global" variables, or at least the language standard doesn't use those terms.  An object has a *lifetime* (*storage duration*), which is the span of time during execution when it exists.  More or less independently of that, an object's name has a *scope*, which is the region of program text in which the name is visible. A variable declared inside a function has *block scope*. It has *automatic storage duration* by default (meaning it exists only while the containing block is executing), but it has *static storage duration* if it's defined with the `static` keyword *or* if it's defined outside any function. A "local" `static` variable will be stored the same way as a "global" variable, which is different from the way a "local" *automatic* variable is stored.

Comment: Actually, global variables **are** placed somewhere. They're typically put in the BSS section of the object file. When an executable is loaded, the BSS is copied by the OS into the data segment of the process.

Comment: That's for global variables with literal initializers. If it's initialized using a function, BSS just contains a default value and the generated code contains startup code that calls the function and updates it.

Comment: Not sure about C++, but C does not mandate a stack or other specific memory management to place **automatic** variables. There are implementations which allocate them in "normal"/unmanaged memory. Also _local_ variables like `static` are never put onto the normal stack.

Comment: @Barmar: Ok, I've deleted the reference to global variables. But for uninitialized (implicitly zero-initialized) global (static) variables, no space is allocated in the object file or executable, just an indication of how much zero-initialized static space is needed. (I think.)

Comment: Right. Although local variables with constant initial values might be put into the data segment, and then the code that initializes local variables can just do a memcpy from there to the stack.

Comment: @Olaf: It's the same with C; the standard doesn't even use the word "stack". But objects with automatic storage duration have a lifetime that's managed in a stack-like last-in first-out manner. This is typically done with a contiguously growing region of memory managed by a "stack pointer", but other implementations (such as linked lists of heap-allocated frames) are possible.

Comment: @KeithThompson: You mean "It's the same with C++"? I already know about C. But thanks, I just assumed that. But no, they can very well be placed in normal memory with fixed addresses. Of course that requires a call-tree analysis. It becomes troublesome for other than tail-recursion, but those implementations typically don't use recursion anyway. I've very much appreciated that on a HC08 MCU for instance.

Comment: Not me DVing. But maybe you should replace "local" by "automatic". `static` variables can be local, too, but are not placed on a stack.

Comment: @Olaf: The OP asked about local variables. I'm not sure I really need to get into the details of the terminology used by the standard.

Comment: Well, he asks where they are placed. As that typically differs for `auto` (C semantics) vs. `static`, I think the difference pretty much matters.

Comment: I do not understand the obsession with stack. Registers are very possible, and in fact preferred on RISC architectures.

Comment: @SergeyA: Well, they still have to store the previous contents of the registers somewhere (and be it a register stack like SPARC). But my point is that you very well can allocate them in normal memory space very efficiently - if there is no head/middle recursion in a program. This is very usefulful for small MCUs which have few CPU-registers and no or only a PC-stack (e.g. PIC).

Comment: @Olaf, I doubt stack means register stack in the answer here, and i wanted emphasize the fact that it should not me mentioned at all here. However, I am not clear what you mean by 'normal' memory space.

Comment: @SergeyA: I wanted to avoid the terms "global" or "static". I mean the same memory space static variables are placed. For instance, a HC08 compiler I once used could place them in a memory area which allowed faster&shorter Op-codes to be used ("direct page"). The even overlapped for functions which did not depend on each other (which included a variant of the _packing problem_),

Comment: @Olaf, space-wise it is all the same memory. There is no real difference from the memory perspective between stack and 'normal' memory - just the one is below the stack boundary, and another is above. But stack boundary is movable, like this first class curtain on domestic flights.

Comment: @SergeyA: I know that since >30 years! Sorry, I apparently cannot make you understand what I mean. I give up.

Comment: @Olaf, I know pretty well what you mean - that your variables were allocated above stack boundary. Sure thing, why not - as long as you are not doing any recursion, this will work wonderfuly well. I am just trying to steer the discussion into more technical lingo.

Comment: @SergeyA: No, that's not what I meant. As I said - just forget it. And, no, you do not "steer" anything anywhere. This has already gone OT.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779395/where-do-local-variables-get-stored-at-compile-time?noredirect=1#comment-61135250) above:

I think you're asking "Q: how does the compiler know how to map a source-level construct (for example,`int x`) to a run-time location (such as  `[esp + 2]`).

Yes, [symbol tables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_symbol_table.htm) play an important role as the compiler parses the source and generates the binary object file.

From the above link:

> Symbol table is an important data structure created and maintained by
>   compilers in order to store information about the occurrence of
>   various entities such as variable names, function names, objects,
>   classes, interfaces, etc. Symbol table is used by both the analysis
>   and the synthesis parts of a compiler.
>
> A symbol table may serve the following purposes depending upon the
>   language in hand:
>
> - To store the names of all entities in a structured form at one place.
> - To verify if a variable has been declared.
> - To implement type checking, by verifying assignments and expressions in the source code are semantically correct.
> - To determine the scope of a name (scope resolution).

But generating and maintaining the symbol table is just one part of the compiler's job.  Here are some good overviews of the entire process:

- [Compiler Overview](http://www.cs.montana.edu/~david.watson5/compilerOverview/compilerOverview.html)
- [A Diagram of the operation of a typical multi-language, multi-platform compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#/media/File:Compiler.svg)
- [Lexer and Parser example for C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#/media/File:Xxx_Scanner_and_parser_example_for_C.gif)

Comment: A pointer must get stored in a symbol table right? Otherwise how does the compiler know how many bytes to increment the pointer? If this pointer is then casted into a different pointer for example from double * to int * , does this information get updated in a symbol table?

Comment: No.  The "pointer" in the example above would be `[esp + 2]`.  But the actual machine code implementation could be *anything*, depending on the platform (this example, x86) and how the compiler chooses to implement locals (in this example, as an offset from the current stack pointer).  The symbol table doesn't *store* a pointer.  The main point is that compiler's code generator *looks up* the variable in the symbol table (to generate the appropriate code).

Comment: but aren't symbol tables also used to find the address of static variables etc. at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Neither C, nor C++ dictate compilers where to store local (or global for that matter) variables.

Depending on the compiler, local variables might be stored in the stack, CPU registers, something else or not stored at all.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are processed at run time, but global variables are at compile time since their scope is predefined. Global variables are stored in data segment of process memory, whereas local gets stored in stack segment.

It can be cross verified with this piece of code:

```
int a= 0;
int main()
{
     int b =0 ;
}


After compiling:

       .file   "test4.c"
        .globl  a
        .bss
        .align 4
        .type   a, @object
        .size   a, 4
a:
        .zero   4
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
~
```