# Storing local variables in compiled object file

Tags: object, variables, compilation, local

According to these answers, [Where does initialized auto variables (local variables) placed in object file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56530702/where-does-initialized-auto-variables-local-variables-placed-in-object-file) and [Where do local variables get stored at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779395/where-do-local-variables-get-stored-at-compile-time), initialized local variables in methods are not stored in the object file but I wonder how that is possible. I mean, if I have the next code, the value 4 has to be codified in the object file like a global initialized variable occupying its corresponding bytes. If it is not codified occupying its bytes, how the program loads the value 4 in the stack when this method is executed?.

```
  void method(){
    int number = 4;
  }
```

Thanks!